# Qt data type serialization

Tags: qt, uart

could someone please provide an example of how one might serialize something like a QColor variable, and then store the bits in a QString/QBitArray/Vector (whatever is optimal). I was hoping to use QDataStream, but the only examples I can find include writing the data to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QColor` can be serialized to `QDataStream` directly, without any conversions. `QDataStream` itself, in turn, can write the data to any `QIODevice` sublass or to a `QByteArray`.
See [Serializing Qt Data Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/datastreamformat.html).

Example:

Serialize color to `QByteArray`:

```
QColor color(Qt::red);

QByteArray ba;
QDataStream out(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << color; // serialized to ba

qDebug() << ba.size();
```

Serialize to TCP socket:

```
auto socket = new QTcpSocket;
socket->connectToHost(addr, port);
if(socket->waitForConnected())
{
    QDataStream out(socket);
    out << color; // written to socket
}
```

Qt has universal serialization rules for major core data types. You can serialize QColor directly to a io-device you need, or to `QByteArray`.

---

You can also present color as a string. But it is not a serialization.

```
QString colorName = color.name(); // the name of the color in the format "#RRGGBB"; i.e. a "#" character followed by three two-digit hexadecimal numbers
qDebug() << colorName;
```

---

About changing concrete bits in a `QByteArray`. See how to convert `QByteArray` to QBitArray and vice versa: https://wiki.qt.io/Working_with_Raw_Data

**Converting Bits to Bytes (and back again)**

```
QByteArray bytes = ...;

// Create a bit array of the appropriate size
QBitArray bits(bytes.count()*8);

// Convert from QByteArray to QBitArray
for(int i=0; i<bytes.count(); ++i) {
    for(int b=0; b<8;b++) {
        bits.setBit( i*8+b, bytes.at(i)&(1<<(7-b)) );
    }
}
```

...

```
QBitArray bits = ...;

// Resulting byte array
QByteArray bytes;

// Convert from QBitArray to QByteArray
for(int b=0; b<bits.count();++b) {
    bytes[b/8] = (bytes.at(b/8) | ((bits[b]?1:0)<<(7-(b%8))));
}
```

---

**Do not forget about Byte Order:** https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatastream.html#setByteOrder

Comment: Ah okay thanks. May I ask, could I actually access the individual bits inside the QByteArray? You see, im trying to simulate a serial UART connection inside my code, so my end goal here is to convert the QColor data into some bits, concatenate that with an opcode indicating that a colour is being sent, and then upload it to a bus as a message. Which of the above methods would be most suitable for such an application? I was also considering QBitArrays.

Comment: @jonah765 mark the answer as a solution, if it is what you need